# Extract Text from a file in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wish to extract the text between the pattern that starts with first occurrences of  "**SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault/inap/si8/begin,**" and
ends with first occurrences "**-----------------------------------------------------------------**"

**Code that I tried**

```
sed -n -e '/SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault\/inap\/si8\/begin,/,/-----------------------------------------------------------------/p' trace.log > operation.log
```

Issue is when the text pattern occurs more than once, like in the below Trace.log there are two occurrences of  "**SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault/inap/si8/begin,**"
and "**-----------------------------------------------------------------**" in the trace.log. 
The code above fetches the text between starting occurrence of pattern **"SCRIPT:m...."** to the ending occurrence of pattern **"----------..."**.

How should I proceed further kindly suggest as reading the file is not an option.

**Input Trace.log**

```
    State[9] 1001010 , SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault/inap/si8/begin,nParam=71
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1232: SIB input 
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1250: stopstats(conte
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1496: Calling SIB orv
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.73: TEL-
    serviceKey 10,
    calledPartyNumber -- void --,
,
    callingPartyNumber '84
,
    callingPartys'0
    iPSSPCapabilit-,
    iPAvailable -- void --,
,
    locationNumber '03
,
    extensions {
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.785: -----------------------------------------------------------------
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.112: TELKOM:SINAP Forward Call Indicators copied in context.
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.146: TELKOM:SINAP Calling Party Number copied in context.
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.156: Called Party BCD Number copied in context
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.169: TELKOM:SINAP Calling Partys Category copied in context.
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.193: LOCATION NUMBER NATURE OF ADDRESS IS:   3
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.244: TELKOM:SINAP Location Number copied in context.
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.249: initial location number is 216F7480553535
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.263: LAI=216F7480553535
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.267: here1216F7480553535
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.283: intLAC:32853
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.290: intCID:13621
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.295: MCC=12F
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.296: MNC=47
38 09:44:06......... begin.cxx.297: LAC=32853
State[9] 1001010 , SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault/inap/si8/begin,nParam=71
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld(context.cld) = 
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_bcd(context.cld_bcd) = 1612
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_bcd_nat(context.cld_bcd_nat) = 0
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_bcd_plan(context.cld_bcd_plan) = 9
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_inn(context.inn_cld) = 4294967295
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_nat(context.nat_cld) = 4294967295
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_plan(context.plan_cld) = 4294967295
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.785: -----------------------------------------------------------------
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_nat(context.nat_cld) = 23
38 09:44:06......... script.cxx.1617: cld_plan(context.plan_cld) =  56
```

Answer (score 0):

With Sed, use /q to stop after the first match.

This appears to be a [duplicate of this question on U&L](https://superuser.com/questions/1343803/extract-text-from-a-file-in-shell#comment2012005_1343803) which has various other solutions as well.

Comment: The link you posted is this exact page. Do you have a link to a different question that is a duplicate of this question?

Comment: Thanks @djsmiley2k, I think I overlooked and missed the Solution [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363219/sed-print-only-first-occurence-of-a-pattern-match)
I tried the below code and it worked liked charm. `sed -n -e '/SCRIPT:main, SIB:orvault\/inap\/si8\/begin,/,/-------------------------------/p; /-------------/q    ' trace.log > operationq.log`